# get_additional_content error call function php

Tags: php

I have this function in which sometimes I get
"Call to undefined method" for the function
$this->get_additional_content() how do I prevent it?

Can a value be assigned inside the array if it does not exist?
example

```
'additional_content' => $this->get_additional_content() ?? "",
```

```json
    public function get_content_html() {
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template(
            $this->template_html,
            array(
                'order'              => $this->object,
                'email_heading'      => $this->get_heading(),
                'additional_content' => $this->get_additional_content(),
                'availability_date'  => $this->availability_date,
                'plain_text'         => false,
                'email'              => $this,
            ),
            '',
            $this->template_base
        );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution

```
'additional_content' => is_callable( array( $this, 'get_additional_content' ) ) ? $this->get_additional_content() : '', // WC 3.7 introduced an additional content field for all emails.
```